# Encrypted files on a server

Tags: security, encryption

There is a way of encrypting the data files stored on the server to harden them against direct access or hacking.

The website is in /var/www as usual and uses PHP to access data on another drive mounted as /home/data if that is any help.  I coded up the site myself and with my level of coding I doubt it it is uncrackable.

I'm also concerned that someone may gain physical access to the computer, and get access to the data that way.

Comment: Have a look on https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html

Comment: also check http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html

Comment: Hi Ahmadgeo,  I'll have a play with eCryptfs and see if it will do the job.  I already have cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html bookmarked along with http://www.hardened-php.net/ ... good sites to keep in mind BEFORE you start.

Comment: Will post as an answer then :)

Comment: check my answer below for a great Linux Foundation publication on Linux Security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned with physical disk security, have a look at [eCryptfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html)
 and [this Linux security article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html).

Also; since you had a break in, you might consider [Console Security](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/security.html).

For overall security, look into these [Ubuntu security guidelines](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/security.html).

One last thing ; have a look at this great [Linux Foundation publication](http://training.linuxfoundation.org/free-linux-training/download-training-materials/introduction-to-linux-security) on Linux security.

Comment: Yes, eCryptfs is what I was looking for.  Thankyou Ahmadgeo.

Comment: Some people believe that unsummarized links are always bad (though I disagree).

Answer (score 3):

If you're serving on plain HTTP, you don't need to entirely worry about a break-in. Anyone can already perform a simple Man in the Middle attack to gain access to a user's account, or can grab the data as it is transmitted.

If you're going to do all encryption and decryption on the server side, rather than on the client, then the data is still being transmitted in the clear between the client and server.

If you want a secure server, then you need to get a valid HTTPS certificate for the site, serve only on HTTPS (automatically redirect any HTTP connection to the HTTPS URL instead), and do all encryption and decryption of data, on the client side, and must be done with a separate key for each user (otherwise, using the same key for all users means any user who is compromised will result in all files for all users having been compromised).

Comment: You're not going to solve theft by encrypting things on the server. It has to be done on the client side. Also, you should probably get an alarm system for the building. Also, get a local security company to "donate" their services to the charity and provide a night guard to stand watch and patrol the property. If the computer gets stolen and the thieves care about getting the data, it's not going to be terribly hard for them to crack it, with your setup.

Comment: Encrypting the files on the server isn't going to solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Although my question was answered by Ahmadgeo I have found it does not solve my problem.  This is my mistake for not understanding what I needed to do.

eCrypt, and any other tools that encrypt files, directories or drives, need to be turned on and off.  As, in my case, the files need to accessible 24/7, so the drive needs to be mounted in an unencrypted state 24/7.  Also, if the server has a power blip and reboots then the files need to be available when it comes back up so we need to save the password somewhere to automate that process.  The end result is that the files are accessible in an unencrypted form whenever the machine is running so there is no protection from hacking or theft of the machine.

I now understand that I need to build into my software a method of encrypting the files and then saving them to disk once they are uploaded (and decrypting on the download).  This way the confidential data can only be accessed by the user with a valid password.  Although the password is used as an encryption key only a MD5 of the password is stored in the machine.

Although dobey makes some good points about using HTTPS, this machine is in my office and is not on a fixed IP address.  Yes, I can provide a "self signed" certificate but at the moment I'm a little worried about what effect a big warning sign about the certificate not being trusted will have on charity workers who still think the cough they had last week was caused by a computer virus.

Comment: apologies for that, I've already flagged my answer for moderator attention to unmark the answer, and wish someone else gets you the perfect answer for your case.

Comment: Don't apologise Ahmadgeo, your answer was correct, it was my understanding of the problem that was wrong.